# How to change the default value of toolbar in WYSIWYG editor in React JS

Tags: reactjs, editor, wysiwyg, draftjs, rte

Have customized only the required toolbar to present in my editor. Need to change the default text of dropdowns present in the WYSIWYG editor

Tried to place the default Value and tried to concat the value with default value but nothing fine as per my requirement.
[Highlighted Font Size toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfDDZ.png)

1. Need to change **"16"** to **"16px"** in my editor.
2. Can we customize like only below fonts should be available in the editor ?
   -Arial
   -Times New Roman
   -Roman